# Where does my application code sit on AWS Elastic Beanstalk EC2 Instance?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Python Flask server to AWS EB.

I have been able to SSH into the EC2 instance and when I go to the root directory and type in the command `ls` I get this;

```
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  local  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

After looking around I made the assumption that my application code is located in the

```
/home/webapp
```

But here I have a problem, I am unable to `cd` into the directory as I get a permission error

```
-bash: cd: webapp/: Permission denied
```

And when I use `sudo` I don't get an error but the directory does not change

```
[ec2-user@ip-###-##-##-### home]$ sudo cd webapp/
[ec2-user@ip-###-##-##-### home]$
```

I have two questions;

1. Where is my application code?
2. Assuming my application code is in the directory `webapp` why is it that `sudo cd` does not work?

Comment: `cd` is a shell builtin, not an external command. You can get a root shell with `sudo -i`

Comment: after using ```sudo -i``` I realize my application code is not in ```webapp```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The application lives under the following directory

```
/var/app/current/
```